# Why is my EmptyStackException not catching here?

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, stack

I'm testing this stack implementation (with a linked list) I have, and so far I'm not having any trouble pushing, popping, and peeking as long as the stack isn't empty.

However, when I try to run this code with a try catch block for EmptyStackException with an empty array, it doesn't catch.

When I run this:

```html
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        //test empty stack
        if(stack.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("1");
        try {
            stack.pop();
        } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
    }
}
```

"1" is printed, and then there is a NullPointerException.

Here is the part of my code that takes care of popping items from a stack:

```html
    public Item pop() throws EmptyStackException{
        s--;
        Item prevFirst = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        return firstVal;
    }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the `pop()` method does it actually throw the `EmptyStackException` when the stack is empty.

Comment: So how exactly would I add that? Sorry, I'm not very familiar with doing this in Java. I kind of just assumed adding it at the top of the code would work.

Comment: Adding the `throws EmptyStackException` in the method signature just tells the compiler that the method might throw that exception.  Within the method itself you still need to `throw new EmptyStackException()` at some point if the stack is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I try to run this code with a try catch block for
> EmptyStackException with an empty array, it doesn't catch.

Because `pop()` does not throw anything.
in your `pop()` method, You should check stack size and if it was empty, then you can instantiate an exception (EmptyStackException) and throw it.

so your code should be something like this:

```
public Item pop()throws EmptyStackException{

    // Check if the stack is empty or not
    if (s == 0){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }

    s--; 
       
    Item prevFirst = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    return firstVal;
}
```